# Check if Android MediaPlayer has been initialized

Tags: android, initialization, android-mediaplayer

How does one check if a `MediaPlayer` object has been initialized? Is there something like a:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
if(mp.isInitialized())
    Log.v("Test", "mp has been initialized. :D ");
else
    Log.v("Test", "mp is NOT yet initialized. :( ");
```

Of course, I checked the API Documentation and there isn't a method like that, but is there a similar approach?

I'm considering just going through my code and just catching the thrown `Exception` if it ever triggers, but I find that unelegant. :P

**EDIT:**

My code was intended to go through like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp;

// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing...

if(mp.isInitialized)
{
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to catch the thrown `Exception` anyways if it's declared to be thrown by that method?

Comment: Hello, @A--C. Please see my edit. My code was intended to proceed as so. And I think I can avoid the `Exception` that way.

Comment: No, what I mean is, `stop()` throws `IllegalStateException`, so you have to either `catch` the Exception **or** declare your method to throw it (via `throws`). So no, there isn't a way to check if it's inititialized, and you're better off catching the exception anyways.

Comment: Oh, understood I see your point. Kindly provide that as an answer so I can accept it, please. Thanks, @A--C! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a method declares that it throws an Exception, when you are using that method, you have two options. Either declare your method to also throw the Exception (passing the buck off so to speak) using the `throws` keyword, or `catch` the exception. You must do one of those things.

Even if the documentation,contained an `isInitialized()` method, if the methods were still throwing `IllegalStateException`s, you must still handle them by one of those two methods.

Also, catching *is* elegant, it allows your app not to crash (crashing isn't elegant) and lets you know something is wrong. If you have a lot of media player calls (such as right after another in the same method), you can put them all under one `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

use a try and catch around the mediaPlayer method invocation and if the IllegalStateException is thrown then it is not initialized

```
try {
   mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {
   // media player is not initialized
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ideas:

1. According to your "intended" code, why can't you use the `isPlaying()` method in place of the desired `isInitialized()`? Don't you only want to call `mp.stop()` if it's actually playing something?
2. How about putting mp.stop() or whatever inside an [OnPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29)?

Comment: Hello, @Ben Jakuben. According to the API Documentation, `isPlaying()` also calls `IllegalStateException` if the internal player engine has not been initialized or has been released. Which is why I'm not considering it.