# MediaPlayer problems

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaPlayer that plays music starting in the main (launcher) activity. I have stumbled across two problems.

1. When I press the home button or my app loses focus in general, the music is still playing.
2. When I return to the main (launcher) activity the mediaPlayer starts again (creates new mediaPlayer) and the result is that there are two MediaPlayers playing the same file simultaneously.

*For the first problem I have tried to stop the music in `onStop()` method but the music stops when I go from main to other activities which is something I don't want and `onDestroy` doesn't work.

My code:

```
if (player == null) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    player.setLooping(true);
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
       player.start();
    }
}
```

P.S I want the music to playing not only in main but on the other activities too.

Comment: Have you tried to stop the MediaPlayer in the `onDestroy()` method?

Comment: For your 1st problem, use ActivityLifeCycleCallback to get calback if your app is visible like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50510902/5689605
For your second problem create a singleton media player in your app, and either play that or stop that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MediaPlayer` is not being properly stopped when you exit. `onStop()` is called whenever the activity stops, either for a higher priority activity to enter, or to be "paused" by another activity (check activity lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)). Try the `stopPlaying()` method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266668/7671879) answer in your `onDestroy()` method.

For the 2nd problem, you can follow one of two ways: either stick with the `stopPlaying()` method from the answer I gave you above, to stop the `MediaPlayer` and set it to null, or check the `MediaPlayer` existance at the beginning of the activity (try checking this before your `MediaPlayer` instantiation, otherwise the `MediaPlayer` will always exists).

Comment: How do I check the MediaPlayer existence?

Comment: You could use `mediaPlayer.isInitialized()`, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371397/7671879) answer if you get an exception, because it might happen. IF you are releasing the mediaplayer before exiting the activity, it should not be initialized when you come back. Are you using any background service for the media player?

Comment: I don't use service for media player. Its on launcher activity class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you release the MediaPlayer resources that you created on destroying the activity, by calling player.release() and nullifying the MediaPlayer in onDestroy() method.

```
     @Override
 protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if(player != null)
             player.stop();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();

      if(player != null)
             player.stop();

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

      if(player != null)
             player.stop();

 }
```